# Equation of hyperbola given the foci and a point on it

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

if $S(5,12)$ and $S'(24,7)$ are the Foci of hyperbola passing through $(0,0)$, find its Equation.

My Try: By the definition of Hyperbola, if $P$ is any point on it and if $S$ and $S'$ are the foci, Then

$$|PS-PS'|=2a$$ Now using $P$ as $(0,0)$ we get $$|13-25|=2a$$ $\implies$ $a=6$

Now if $P(x,y)$ is any point we have

$$PS^2+PS'^2-2PSPS'=4a^2=144$$  using distance formula and rearranging the terms we get

$$(x^2+y^2-29x-19y+325)^2=(x^2+y^2-10x-24y+169)(x^2+y^2-48x-14y+625)$$

if we simplify above we get equation of the form $$ax^2+2hxy+by^2+2gx+2fy=0$$

But i feel this algebra as lengthy is there any other method to find the equation?

Comment: You can use [Cinderella](http://cinderella.de/) to enter the input and print the matrix of the conic by writing `C0.matrix` as a formula. In your case you get $$\begin{pmatrix}a&h&g\\h&b&f\\g&f&c\end{pmatrix}\approx\begin{pmatrix}-0.09&0.04&0.89\\0.04&0.05&-1\\0.89&-1&0\end{pmatrix}$$ Writing `apply(C0.matrix,i,apply(i,j,guess(j)))` you can even try to turn these decimal fractions into rational numbers, in this case $$\frac1{2508}\begin{pmatrix}-217&95&2244\\95&119&-2508\\2244&-2508&0\end{pmatrix}$$ which is in fact the correct answer. But I'm not sure that's what you are after.